# What must be true for $Ax = b$ to imply that $x = bA^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

What must be true for $Ax = b$ to imply that $x = bA^{-1}$? Assume that $A$ is a matrix, and $x$ and $b$ are column vectors.

> 1) Is A singular or nonsingular?

From the given (implied) equation, it seems safe to assume that A has an inverse, in which case A must be nonsingular.

> 2) Is A a square matrix?

To have an inverse, a matrix needs to be a square matrix, so yes.

> 3) Is the nullspace of A zero or 1 dimensional?

Following from the reasonings above, A is 0 dimensional.

> 4) Is the matrix A 1x1?

It works, so I think I can say yes.

> 5) Or "none of the above".

This choice then can be ruled out.

Am I right in thinking this way?

The problem I have with thinking that A may indeed be invertible, is that b is a single column vector. Hence $A^{-1}$ will probably have to be a 1xn matrix for $bA^{-1}$ to work. But then if so, since it's not a square matrix, it actually won't have an inverse. Does that mean "none of the above" (which apprently isn't the correct answer,at least by itself)?

I'm not too confident about my answers because usually, $x=A^{-1}b$, not $x=bA^{-1}$, and it's confusing me a lot. Any help would really be appreciated!

Update: just to be clear, there are no typos!
[image]

Comment: The product $bA^{-1}$ is not defined unless $b$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix (scalar), in which case $A$ will also be $1 \times 1$ (for it to be invertible it should at least be a square matrix).

Comment: Either this was meant as a trick question, or there is a typo

Comment: "*because usually $x=A^{-1}b$ not $x=bA^{-1}$*"  Exactly!  $Ax=b$, if $A^{-1}$ exists (*which it isn't guaranteed to exist*), then you would *left multiply* both sides by $A^{-1}$ to get $A^{-1}(Ax)=A^{-1}(b)$ simplifying to $x=A^{-1}b$.  Now... if we had instead that $x=bA^{-1}$ that would mean $A^{-1}b=bA^{-1}$ which is an uncommon thing to have happen.

Comment: I suppose that if $Ax = b$ has no solutions, then the implication holds vacuously

Comment: $b$ is column vector, it says in text. $\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n  \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't think there's a typo in my post, but I can check again, if you'd like—could u tell me where u think the typo may be? The original question I was asked, btw, probably doesn't contain typos, apparently

Comment: @singularity I think that instead of $bA^{-1}$, the right hand side should be $A^{-1}b$. Alternatively, it could be that instead of $Ax$, the left hand side should be $xA$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh, it's right as it is—see my update

Comment: Then if it is correct, it is a trick question. Where exactly did you come across this question? I still think it's likely to be a typo, but a typo that the author of the question made.

Comment: @AnuragA—So to summarise, A is nonsingular, a square matrix, has a nullspace of 0 dimension, and is 1x1?

Answer (score 1):

If we are meant to take the question literally, then the answer is as follows.

In the case that $A$ is a scalar (i.e. a matrix with one entry), then clearly the statement holds when $A \neq 0$.

If $x,b$ are column-vectors of size greater than $1$ and $A$ is a square matrix for which the product $Ax$ is conformable, then the expression $bA^{-1}$ is undefined, which means that the statement $x = bA^{-1}$ is always false. In order for the implication to be true, $Ax = b$ must always be false.

It is not clear whether the statement refers to a fixed vector $b$ or arbitrary vectors $b$ (i.e. the statement should hold for all choices of $x$ **and** all choices of $b$). If $x,b$ are both arbitrary vectors, then $Ax = b$ is always *sometimes* true since we can take $x = b = 0$.

If $b$ is meant to be a fixed vector, then the statement $Ax = b$ will always be false (for all $x$) iff $Ax = b$ has no solution, which holds iff $A$ fails to be invertible and $b$ lies outside the column space of $A$.